# Kubernetes basic pod logging

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I'm trying to setup basic logging to get all my pod logs at a single place. Following is the pod-spec I have created but couldn't find the trace of the logs in the location mentioned. What could be missing in the template below?

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: counter
    spec:
      containers:
    - name: count
        image: busybox
        args: [/bin/sh, -c,
        'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)" >> /u01/kubernetes_prac/logs/log_output.txt; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /u01/kubernetes_prac/logs
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: With `empty_dir`, logs are produced in the container in the mountPath you specify. Logs are also on the node but under an other location (managed by kubernetes/docker).

Comment: I could see the logs created in the container inside the Pod and also on the host machine (worker node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
volumes:
  - name: varlog
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/logs
```

and check the node logs on that location

Comment: I could see the logs created in the container inside the Pod and also on the host machine (worker node).

Comment: I have pod.. I want to store logs generated by that pod i.e logs generated by kubectl logs podname What will be my args?

Answer (score 0):

Look into fluentd , to save ur logs somewhere(s3, elastic etc)